# Can I disable the Minio web GUI?

Tags: docker, minio

I wonder if it is possible to disable the Minio GUI and only expose the REST API.

I am using the Docker image *minio/minio* and have to run Minio under a *sub-path like example.com/the/path/to/minio*, which is not supported by Minio and breaks the graphical UI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting MINIO_BROWSER env should disable the minio browser

> MINIO_BROWSER=off

Comment: Thanks! Quite easy to find, if you know the GUI is called browser ;)